# Como remover uma Chave de um JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Suponhamos o seguinte JSON:

```
{"id": 1, "preco": 100, "detalhe": "nenhum"}
```

Se eu construir um array com 100 desses objetos e quiser tirar a chave "detalhe" de todos, por exemplo, é possível (sem ser na mão)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A partir do `ES6` você pode utilizar a função [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) usando ["Atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao) juntamente com a ["Sintaxe de Espalhamento (Spread syntax)"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para eliminar os atributos que deseja remover:

```
const nova = lista.map(({ remover, ...outros }) => outros);
```

Aplicando ao seu exemplo:

```js
const lista = [
  {"id": 1, "preco": 100, "detalhe": "nenhum"},
  {"id": 2, "preco": 150, "detalhe": "todos"},
  {"id": 3, "preco": 200, "detalhe": "alguns"},
];

const nova = lista.map(({ detalhe, ...demais }) => demais);

console.log('Original:', JSON.stringify(lista));
console.log('Resultado:', JSON.stringify(nova));
```

> [**Atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao).
>
> A sintaxe de **atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)** é uma expressão JavaScript que possibilita extrair dados de arrays ou objetos em variáveis distintas.
>
> ```
> var a, b, rest;
> [a, b] = [1, 2];
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
>
> [a, b, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
> console.log(rest); // [3, 4, 5]
>
> ({a, b} = {a:1, b:2});
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
> ```

---

> [**Sintaxe de Espalhamento (Spread syntax)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
>
> **Sintaxe de Espalhamento (Spread syntax)** permite um objeto iterável tal como uma expressão de array ou uma string ser expandida onde zero ou mais argumentos (para chamadas de funções) ou elementos (para arrays literais) são esperados, ou um objeto ser expandido onde zero ou mais pares propriedade:valor (para objetos literais) são esperados.
>
> ```
> function sum(x, y, z) {
>   return x + y + z;
> }
>
> const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
>
> console.log(sum(...numbers));
> // expected output: 6
>
> console.log(sum.apply(null, numbers));
> // expected output: 6
> ```

---

> [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
>
> O método map() invoca a função callback passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.
>
> ```
> var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
> var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
> // roots é [1, 2, 3], numbers ainda é [1, 4, 9]
> ```

Comment: Muito interessante, mesmo eu conhecendo o `map` e o `operador spread` eu nunca os tinha usado dessa forma! Obrigado pela informação.

Answer (score 4):

Em **javascript** você poderia fazer da seguinte forma, supondo o seguinte código:

```
let meuObjeto = {"id": 1, "preco": 100, "detalhe": "nenhum"}

delete meuObjeto.detalhe
```

Ou

```
delete meuObjeto["detalhe"]
```

Agora se você estiver um **array** com **100** desses objetos é só fazer um laço de repetição usando uma das formas que é sucesso!

Segue abaixo um exemplo, considerando que o elemento `meuArray` é um `Array` com 100 objetos do tipo mostrado acima.

```
meuArray.forEach(elemento => delete elemento.detalhe) // Ou da outra forma
```